# Is it possible to use one input to put multiple integers into a list?

Tags: python, list, input

```
marks = input("Please enter marks ")

for i in range(1,21):
  marksList = []
  marksList.append(marks)
  
print(marksList)
```

This is my code. I want to use the same variable and enter 20 marks using the same input, and then append it to the `marks` List. Is there any way I can?

I tried researching but nothing was showing up properly.

Comment: What are "marks"? Numerical only or text? FWIW, you also ask for all marks at once, e.g. space-separated (or any other separator). Then (if numeric): `markslist = [int(x.strip()) for x in marks.split()]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `input` command inside the loop, because you need to repeat the request to user to enter the content in `marks` variable; it's necessary remove `marksList` variable from loop to avoid to turn the list void in each interaction:

```
marksList = []

for i in range(1,21):
 marks = input("Please enter marks ")
 marksList.append(marks)
  
print(marksList)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input_string = input("Enter a list of integers separated by spaces: ") 
int_list = [int(x) for x in input_string.split()] # split the string into a list of integers

print(int_list)  # print the list of integers
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this would be preferable?

```py
n = 20
marks = []
while len(marks) < n:
    isfirst = not marks
    ans = input(f'Please enter {n - len(marks)}{"" if isfirst else " additional"} marks: ')
    marks += [int(i.strip()) for i in ans.split()]

print(f'Thanks. The marks are {marks}')
```

Example interaction:

```
Please enter 20 marks: 1 4 2 0 10 -32 10 22
Please enter 12 additional marks: 1 2 5 9 2000
Please enter 7 additional marks: 9 8 4 1 5 2
Please enter 1 additional marks: 1
Thanks. The marks are [1, 4, 2, 0, 10, -32, 10, 22, 1, 2, 5, 9, 2000, 9, 8, 4, 1, 5, 2, 1]
```